# ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): NullInjectorError: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[FormBuilder]

Tags: angular, angular6, angular7-router

in my angular app when I add routes in gifts-routing.module.ts this error appears 
and when i remove the routes it works
but i still need to route
so how can i solve this error

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): NullInjectorError: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[FormBuilder]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[FormBuilder]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for FormBuilder!
NullInjectorError: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[FormBuilder]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[FormBuilder]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for FormBuilder!
```

**gifts.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

import { GiftsRoutingModule } from './gifts-routing.module';
import { GiftListComponent } from './components/gift-list/gift-list.component';
import { GiftFormComponent } from './components/gift-form/gift-form.component';
import { SharedModule } from '../shared/shared.module';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [GiftListComponent, GiftFormComponent],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    GiftsRoutingModule,
    SharedModule
  ]
})
export class GiftsModule { }
```

**gifts-routing.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { LayoutComponent } from '../shared/components/layout/layout.component';
import { GiftListComponent } from './components/gift-list/gift-list.component';


const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: LayoutComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path:'',
        component: GiftListComponent
      }
    ]
  }
];


@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class GiftsRoutingModule { }
```

and I also import the **ReactiveFormsModule** and **FormsModule** inside my shared module

**shared.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

import { SharedRoutingModule } from './shared-routing.module';
import { LayoutComponent } from './components/layout/layout.component';
import { NavbarComponent } from './components/layout/navbar/navbar.component';

import { ReactiveFormsModule, FormsModule } from '@angular/forms'
import {
  MatButtonModule,
  MatCardModule,
  MatInputModule,
  MatIconModule,
  MatTabsModule,
  MatTableModule,
  MatPaginatorModule,
  MatSortModule,
  MatProgressSpinnerModule,
  MatSlideToggleModule,
  MatDialogModule,
  MatSelectModule,
  MatDatepickerModule,
  MatToolbarModule,
  MatListModule,
  MatMenuModule,
  MatSidenavModule,
  MatTooltipModule,
  MatRadioModule,
  MatStepperModule,
  MatCheckboxModule,
  MatExpansionModule,
  MatProgressBarModule,
  MatNativeDateModule,
} from '@angular/material';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { FloatingButtonComponent } from './components/floating-button/floating-button.component';
import { ConfirmComponent } from './components/confirm/confirm.component';
@NgModule({
  declarations: [LayoutComponent, NavbarComponent, FloatingButtonComponent, ConfirmComponent],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    SharedRoutingModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    RouterModule,
    FormsModule,
    CommonModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    MatMenuModule,
    MatSidenavModule,
    MatListModule,
    MatToolbarModule,
    MatIconModule,
    MatCardModule,
    MatTabsModule,
    MatInputModule,
    MatTableModule,
    MatPaginatorModule,
    MatSortModule,
    MatProgressSpinnerModule,
    MatSlideToggleModule,
    MatDialogModule,
    MatSelectModule,
    MatDatepickerModule,
    MatProgressBarModule,
    MatTooltipModule,
    MatRadioModule,
    MatStepperModule,
    MatCheckboxModule,
    MatExpansionModule,
    MatNativeDateModule,

  ],
  exports: [
    CommonModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    RouterModule,
    FormsModule,
    CommonModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    MatMenuModule,
    MatSidenavModule,
    MatListModule,
    MatToolbarModule,
    MatIconModule,
    MatCardModule,
    MatTabsModule,
    MatInputModule,
    MatTableModule,
    MatPaginatorModule,
    MatSortModule,
    MatProgressSpinnerModule,
    MatSlideToggleModule,
    MatDialogModule,
    MatSelectModule,
    MatDatepickerModule,
    MatProgressBarModule,
    MatTooltipModule,
    MatRadioModule,
    MatStepperModule,
    MatCheckboxModule,
    MatExpansionModule,
  ],
  entryComponents: [ConfirmComponent]
})
export class SharedModule { 

}
```

what I should do to solve this error, please?

Comment: could you provide the AppModule?

Comment: Need more info, It complains about formbuilder injection, Can you provide the code where you are using and injecting FORMBUILDER, also child route array has an empty path, give either parent or children non empty path.

Comment: Have you used `FormBuilder` in your any component? if yes then provide that code!

Comment: if you use FormBuilder in any component without declare please import that in component file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to move the imports `shared module` to `main module`
`FormsModule` and `ReactiveFormsModule` do not work as `shared module`.

Answer (score 4):

I got this error when I tried to add a component in constructor as a service. I've resolved this issue by using @injectable().

you can use

```
@Injectable({
   providedIn: 'root',
})
export class component{}
```

Answer (score 0):

Import this in your app module.ts :

```
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
```

And In Imports :

```
imports: [
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
  ],
```

Comment: but it is already working on another typical module so why here it is not
can you explain that for me, please?

Comment: I am not getting u..But in my opinion it should work..The fact is that in the component where u are using the formbuilder instance you have to import the Formsmodule and Reactive formsmodule in that particular component's parent Module.ts

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I had to include ConsoleService, which ng-select exports as "es"

So, in my app.module.ts, I had to add:`import { NgSelectConfig } from '@ng-select/ng-select'; import { ɵs } from '@ng-select/ng-select';`

And in providers, I added: NgSelectConfig and es